# Probems using 2 For and a AppendTo to cycle through my Equation to solve some matrixes

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, matrix

I am trying to solve a few problems here. I have an equation with multiple variables that I am trying to solve in For loop method. I will attach the file below.

In addition I am trying to get it to ListContourPlot the results.

I am getting a series of partd errors saying it is longer than the depth of the object on the very first iteration, which should not be happening.

I have tried changing around the equation, editing the For loops, and a few other things but to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated.

[Link to Mathematica File](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/27055131/test1.nb)

Comment: put the code here not a link

Comment: One recommendation, instead of `AppendTo` and `For`, use [`Join`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Join.html) and [`Do`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Do.html). `AppendTo` and `For` are highly inefficient and slow, while `Join` and `Do` are optimized and significantly faster. Instead of `AppendTo[list, elem]`, use `list = Join[list, {elem}]`.

Comment: In your case, since you are using `AppendTo` to collect results, try using `Do`, [`Reap`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reap.html), and [`Sow`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sow.html).

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 1):

[Here is the fixed notebook](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=81993551646236811976).

Your main problems were that the third elements of the first argument in `ListContourPlot` were imaginary and that you switched two values in `Part` in `fsingle`. In the notebook, I highlighted lines I have changed and wrote why I changed them in the comments (there were some inefficiencies).

However, please try to post your actual code in the question next time, not a link.

Comment: Thank you for your help, the workbook already loads far faster than it did before. I will have to read up on Reap, Do, and Sow.

Comment: A question for you JHM. When you did the Reap[Do[So.... what does the [[-1,1]] at the end represent?

Comment: `Reap` outputs the `Sow`ed data, sorted by tags (`Sow` can take a second argument, the tag). Since no tag was used, the tag will be `Null`, which we do not want; we only need the `Sow`ed data, which is the second (or first from last) element of the list, hence the `Part` and `-1`. `Sow` also puts an extra `List` around the data, so we can get rid of it, using the `1` in `Part`. It is necessary if you want only the `Sow`ed data.

Comment: Thank you again JHM, I appreciate it.